# How can I get PyCharm to use the Vagrant Directories rather than my development machines?

Tags: django, vagrant, pycharm

When I try to run my Django app via PyCharm inside of Vagrant, it sends my Windows Path over SSH which then provides an error in the shell:

> > ssh://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2200/usr/bin/python -u C:/Projects/dev_project/dev/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
>
> bash: line 0: cd:
> C:/Projects/dev_project/dev: No such
> file or directory /usr/bin/python: can't open file
> 'C:/Projects/dev_project/dev/manage.py':
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I created a Python Project in PyCharm (and instantiated a Django Project in a sub-folder) in order to incorporate Vagrant.

```
dev_project (PyCharm project root)
  |--.vagrant
  |--dev (Django project root)
       |--dev
       |--app
       |--manage.py
  |--Vagrantfile
```

**In Settings**

I enabled Django Support (providing the Windows Paths as there is no other option) in *Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Django.*
The Vagrant Python Interpreter is selected as the Project Interpreter (and Django Console & Python Console)

**In Run Configurations**

My host is 0.0.0.0 and port is 8000
My Python Interpreter is the Vagrant Environment. I am also adding the Content Roots & Source Roots to the Python Path.

The bizarre problem is it was working fine, and then I exited out and it broke again.  Also, I do not have 'Working Directory' explicitly defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog article](http://reactuatesoftware.com/configuring-pycharm-django-and-vagrant/) showed me my issue, as I did not have my Path Mappings setup within my Run Configuration.

From the Article (Configure Your Project to Use the Correct Interpreter):

- Select **Run->Edit Configurations**…
- Select the configuration on the right PyCharm created for us. In my case it was called “session_tracker”.
- Change “Python interpreter” to our newly created one.
- A new field will appear. Click the button next to “Path mappings”.  A new window will appear to let you create your mappings.
- Vagrant shares a local directory with the VM. My Vagrant file is configured so a folder is called “django_shared” in our [VagrantFolder] locally, and “django_shared” in the home directory on the VM are the same. You need to enter the full paths of each of those in the “Edit Path Mappings” window.  - Click the + button to create a new mapping, then enter the values for the mapping on each side.

Answer (score 0):

When no other option works I do the following:

- Create seperate virtualenv in my local directory
- Reconfigure PyCharm to use the interpreter in that venv
- Restart PyCharm

Maybe not a very good solution, but works.